# Can not dynamically remove input element from form

Tags: jquery

**Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T8fUY/**

A very simple situation. Add input fields dynamically and also remove them if necessary. I've seen countless examples but I can't get the remove function to work. Here is my HTML:

```
<ol> 
    <li id="caseform-FileUploader">
        <input type="button" id="caseform-AddFile" value="Add File"> 
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
var filenumber = $('li#caseform-FileUploader ul li').size() + 1; // set which file number this is

$("#caseform-AddFile").click(function () {
    //add the input within the ul that is in #caseform-FileUploader
    $('<li><input type="file" name="upload' + filenumber + '"/> <a href="#" id="caseform-RemoveFileUpload">Remove</a></li>').appendTo("#caseform-FileUploader ul");
    filenumber++;
    return false;
});

//When the hyperlink is clicked, remove this parent li
$('#caseform-RemoveFileUpload').on('click', function () {
    if (filenumber > 0) {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        filenumber--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

It adds inputs perfectly fine.... but the remove function is not working when a user clicks on the remove hyperlink.

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements. You need to pass nearest static container.

```
//When the hyperlink is clicked, remove this parent li
$("#caseform-FileUploader").on('click','#caseform-RemoveFileUpload', function () {
    if (filenumber > 0) {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        filenumber--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Additionally, As IDs must be unique I suggest you use class for `caseform-RemoveFileUpload` anchor

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8fUY/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need event delegation, to bind event for dynamically added elements. The time you are binding event on element with id `caseform-RemoveFileUpload` does not exists but added later in the `caseform-AddFile` click event handler.

```
$(document).on('click', '#caseform-RemoveFileUpload', function () {
    if (filenumber > 0) {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        filenumber--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

#### Delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use id for the remove button since id must be unique(you are adding multiple remove buttons with the same id), use a class attribute to group them.

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as you are dealing with dynamic elements

```
//don't use id selector with element selector
var filenumber = $('#caseform-FileUploader ul li').size() + 1; // set which file number this is

$("#caseform-AddFile").click(function () {
    //add the input within the ul that is in #caseform-FileUploader
    $('<li><input type="file" name="upload' + filenumber + '"/> <a href="#" class="caseform-RemoveFileUpload">Remove</a></li>').appendTo("#caseform-FileUploader ul");
    filenumber++;
    return false;
});

//When the hyperlink is clicked, remove this parent li
$('#caseform-FileUploader').on('click', '.caseform-RemoveFileUpload', function () {
    if (filenumber > 0) {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        filenumber--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cGsAK/)

Answer (score 0):

You have dynamically added elements. They have to work.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#caseform-RemoveFileUpload', function () {
if (filenumber > 0) {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    filenumber--;
}
return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T8fUY/1/